# How to make layout_height and layout_width with equal size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some image that have resolution 320x320.

For the `layout_width` it set the value `fill_parent`

but I do not know what should I set for the `layout_height`

I want to have equal size for height and width.

If I set `layout_height=wrap_content` the width is twice bigger then the height...

How can I tall some layout to fill all the space in x but to have y size just as the size of x

Comment: Why don't you set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` too? and then position the view wherever you want?

Comment: because that is not what I want to achieve, I want to be the full size for the weight (fill_parent) and to be the same size for the y axis as the x axis

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

now set the height dynamically using width.

this is the width of the device screen, as you are using layout_width = fill parent.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly setting the layout_height

eg

```
android:layout_height="320dip"
```

Comment: yes, that is one trick , but I should support this for any screen size and density

Answer (score 1):

From within your activity's `onCreate(...)` method, immediately after calling `setContentView(...);`

Use this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.getLayoutParams().width = image.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I set layout_height=wrap_content the width is twice bigger then the
>   height...

I think that is because Whenever you set height/width to `WRAP_CONTENT` *it makes the layout as much wide or tall that it can accomodate the Background of the layout, the child views of the layout* so it will grow even bigger if you add some more child to the layout

And when set to `FILL_PARENT` then it *takes the whole visible left screen area*.

> Solutions

1. Either you can give some fix size using `dp` to your layout, and then you will have to make different XML file for diff size of devices.
2. you can try and use the LinearLayout's `weightSum` and `layout_weight` attributes and manage the height and width of your layout by appllying proper weight. [I personally recommand to use `weight`]